# Trouble building IDL library using makefile and gfortran on a Windows 10 running WSL Ubuntu

Tags: makefile, fortran, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gfortran, idl

my knowledge is very shallow so I hope I am explaining the problem clearly.

I am trying to build a library for IDL which uses makefiles https://sourceforge.net/projects/irbem/files/irbem/4.4.0/

Judging by the contents inside the makefile, it should have support for Windows. Following the instructions on the *updated* github page (note here that I am trying to install the older version that is not on github) https://github.com/PRBEM/IRBEM

After entering `make OS=win32 ENV=mingw all` I recieve a plethora of warning messages such as:

```
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE...
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory '%IDLINC%' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination..
```

And in the end when I use
`make OS=win32 ENV=mingw install` I do not obtain the results I want which is some sort of .dll file... I suspect maybe I am using a newer version of gfortran however, I can't seem to figure out how to downgrade or resolve these issues. If anyone can help me, that would be greatly appreicated.

I am using Windows 10, with Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem Linux.

Comment: Those warnings about the loops are warnings, not errors. The compiler is still supporting that [old style of writing loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63730527/3157076). You will need to look at other factors if you are not getting your build objects.

Comment: @francescalus That is very helpful to know!

Comment: You need to tell us the error messages you got in the last step. Or better the full output. What *exactly* happened in the last step?

Comment: `Nonexistent include directory '%IDLINC%'` - suggests the makefile is written for Windows (MS-DOS), not Linux (shell). So that'll never work in WSL. You'll have to patch it yourself.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the feed back, that is actually the exact issue I am trying to solve right now, see below. Could you point me to some resources regarding how I can "patch" this issue?

Comment: @VladimirF Actually there is no error message! That is the annoying part. The program outputs a build complete however, when I try to use the library with idl, idl spits out "not a valid win32 application". I suspect it is due to the warning assosciated with the %IDLINC% line, do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Patch it by changing from MS-DOS syntax to Make/shell syntax, from `%IDLINC%` to `$IDLINC`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to speculate that you shouldn't be working in WSL, in the first place; maybe those sources/makefiles are supposed to be executed on the Windows side, withing an msys2/mingw64 shell...then, they would produce a *.dll or still an *.so kind of file.

The msys2/mingw64 environment is a linux-like environment with building tool-chaing and many commands as in Linux, but it is not Linux, they are actually Windows executables. And, so, when you compile a program with that environment, you also get a Windows executable.

My 2 cents.

Comment: That is an excellent idea. I tried to use mingw64 enviroment to redo my building this time using `mingw32-make OS=win32 ENV=mingw all` however, it still do not get my desired result. I feel like it is due to this line of warning `f951.exe: Warning: Nonexistent include directory '%IDLINC%' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]` Do you have any idea how to solve this so my system finds %IDLINC%? I suspect it has something to do with idl files, but I don't know how to help the system "find" them.

Comment: That looks like an environment variable.  Can you pre-set an environment variables with the name of IDLINC and with a value of the full path to the directory where the include files of the IDL library are?  Something like ""export IDLINC=/c/path/to/idl/include"

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried to set "IDLINC" to the lib directory /idl88/lib, and I also tried it with the external include directory /idl88/external/include, but I still recieve the same warning from the makefile. `Warning: Nonexistent include directory "%IDLINC%"`

Comment: You need to know your own setup and configuration regarding the msys2/mingw64 environment and the pre-existing "Windows"-environment/CMD-shell, and whether they are aware of each other in the sense of including paths of each other in their own PATH variable. 

There are two ways to launch bash, one where it is kind of standalone and another where it inherits PATH from the "Windows" side.

Comment: Furthermore, after installing msys2/mingw64, it is up to you whether you leave your "Windows" side alone or make it aware of your msys2 installation...again, in the form of adding msys2/mingw64 paths to your "Windows" PATH system variable.

Comment: Another aspect regards which shell is launched when the make file gets to the recipe of a target.  Even though you may be at the BASH prompt, it could very well be that the recipe is launching a CMD prompt; thus, this prompt not only must be aware of whatever you need from msys2/mingw64, but also, it is expecting paths to be in the formt of c:/path/to/someb/lib as opposed to /idl88/lib or evern /c/path/to/some/lib.

Comment: Experiment with a trivial makefile. First, for example, find out what shell is being used inside a recipe by attempting to echo an environment variable with either $var (for bash) or %var% (for cmd) and see which one is accepted; or, attempt to echo a variable that only exists, say, in bash (HOSTNAME, PWD, MANPATH)


    dollar:
        echo "bash? echo var with dollar: $HOME"
    percent:
        echo "cmd? echo var with percent: %HOME%"

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to use markdown in comments; but, in my previous comment.

Comment: Then try:
make dollar
make percent
If you are in cmd, then you need to set IDLINC accordingly, like "c:/path/to/idl88/lib"

Comment: There is a limit as to how large a comment can be...it's very short...annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal makefile to test for shell inside the recipe:

```
dollar:
    @echo "bash? echo var with dollar: $HOME"
percent:
    @echo "cmd? echo var with percent: %HOME%"
```

Then try:
make dollar
make percent
If you are in cmd, then you need to set IDLINC accordingly, like "c:/path/to/idl88/lib"