# CABSDock:fortran 2018 deleted feature

Tags: gfortran

warning:

```
<stdin>:1879:72: Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination
statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 7000 at (1)
```

PLease help me in this regard

I was running the following command for CABSDock:

```
CABSdock -k 10 -M --contact-threshold-aa 5.5 --filtering-mode each --image-file-format svg -i ~/attachments/adeA.pdb -p ~/attachments/1.pdb --dssp-command /usr/local/bin/mkdssp.
```

I am working with a source code of CABSDock that might have been written before the most recent version of gfortran as (default is 'gfortran -O2').

Comment: What help are you after? If you want to change the code, [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63730527/3157076); if you want to ignore the warning, ignore it; if you want to suppress the warning, use a compiler/compiler option that doesn't give the warning or is a Fortran 2008 compiler.

Comment: What is your problem? Do you have any other problem besides the warning? It is just a warning, not an error. Does the code produce the result you need?