# constant number before a statement in fortran code

Tags: fortran

I came across something and I am unable to find any explanation for it, consider the following two code snippets.

THIS RUNS

```
Program Hello

implicit none

print *, "hello world"

1 print *, "one"

print *, "bye world"

End Program Hello
```

output:
hello world
one
bye world

THIS DOES NOT COMPILE

```
Program Hello

implicit none

print *, "hello world"

1 
print *, "one"

print *, "bye world"

End Program Hello
```

```
error:\
main.f95:16:1:\
   16 | 1\
      | 1\
Error: Statement label without statement at (1)
```

Anyone knows what is happening here? Why does the first one compile and run?

PS: it is not useful code, however I saw "1 continue" in some Fortran code, and was just wondering what that even achieves?

EDIT: SO it is likely a statement label, How are Fortran statement labels used? are they purely cosmetic or actually provide some usage?

Comment: can't really find an explanation for it.

Comment: Well, if you put ```goto 1``` just before your End Program statement you will find one of the (VERY OLD) uses for them. It is possible (and recommended) to avoid statement labels and goto in modern fortran.

Comment: While it may be possible to avoid `goto` in modern Fortran, statement labels can be convenient while reading a file `read(10,'(A)',end=10,err=20)`.

Comment: If you use "iostat=(your status variable)" then you can test your status variable against iostat_end (in iso_fortran_env, since Fortran 2003), or various types of error. There is no longer any need for statement labels in this context (nor other contexts, such as format statements, since you could just declare the format as a character variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `1` here is not a numeric constant; it is a *statement label*. (Recall that expressions like the actual constant `1` cannot appear in arbitrary places, or as the only part of a statement as can be found in some other languages.)

A statement label (Fortran 2018 6.2.5):

> provides a means of referring to an individual statement

That's it: it's a label to say that the `print` statement in the first example can be referred to be a reference to the label `1`.

A statement label consists of between one and six digits, at least one of which is not a zero. Within a scope, they must be unique (ignoring leading zeros).

A label must be followed by a statement with non-blanks.  This makes

```
1
```

invalid.

Not all statements may be labelled, and not all statements are usefully labelled.  Labels are meaningful to the program only in the following cases:

1. As a statement to be "jumped" to (`go to`, etc.)
2. Necessarily as part of a `format` statement (so it can be referenced)
3. In a non-block DO construct (obsolete in Fortran 2018)

In other cases a statement label is meaningful only to programmers (say as documentation).

```
1 continue
```

is commonly used in cases like the non-block DO:

```
do 1 i=1, 10
1 continue
```

(but we don't do these [any longer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63733073/3157076)).

Or similarly as a do-nothing jump target:

```
read(unit, err=1)
...
1 continue
```

(if we aren't using `iostat=...` which we should).

Comment: Makes sense. Wondering how the 
```
do 1 i=1, 10
print *, i
1 continue
```
works? The label for continue is 1, so what does do 1 mean? why doesn't it require an end do?

Comment: http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~gronbech/intfor/node18.html answers that question. never mind.

Answer (score 2):

Fortran 2018 in the section about statement labels:

> 6.2.5 Statement labels
>
> 2 If a statement is labeled, the statement shall contain a nonblank
> character. ...

You cannot have a label on an empty line, it is not valid Fortran. You can put the `CONTINUE` statement to your lable, it does nothing.

It is quite common to find `CONTINUE` statements with labels terminating a `DO` loop in old source codes.

Other than that, stament labels were also commonly used for `FORMAT` statements and as targets of `GO TO`. There are other, less common, use cases too.

So, regarding your edit:

```
DO 10 I = 1,99
  PRINT *, I
10 CONTINUE
```

is a do loop and

```
GO TO 10
```

is a jump to that end line with the statement.