# Does the code following the end of a loop label execute in the loop

Tags: fortran

In this loop:

```
DO 180 J=1,9
K=9*(I-1)+J
180 ZX(K)=0.D0
```

How many times will `(ZX(K)=0.D0` execute? Once or 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: 9 times

see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z400073d15115/index.html

> **DO Loop Range**
>
> The range of a DO loop consists of all of the executable statements
> that appear following the DO statement, **up to and including the
> terminal statement**.

Comment: Note if more than 1 loop shares the statement labelled by 180 then this was deleted from the Fortran language in the 2018 standard (according to MR&C). If it's just a single loop that's fine. For some value of fine living in about 1970.

Comment: @IanBush, F2018 deleted the non-block DO in its entirety. (More detail than can possibly be useful for such a simple case in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63730527/3157076).)

Comment: @francescalus Which is what I thought - but when I checked MR&C Appendix B.6 it talks exclusively about "shared do-loop termination" and "Nexted do-loops", hence the qualification (And I was waiting for your response ;) )

Comment: @IanBush, unfortunately my M&R/MR&Cs are ancient, but that's a surprise. I don't recall when in F2018 development non-block deletion was settled, so could be a timing issue on publication?

Comment: @francescalus Indeed. I will try to reproduce the whole section later incase I am misunderstanding. First, lasagne.

Comment: Shared loop termination and termination on a statement other than END Do or CONTINUE were placed on the Obsolescent list in Fortran 95, (see B.2(2)).  These were finally deleted in F2018.